# Como carregar apenas o atributo ID em Relacionamento Many-To-One no EF?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Possuo dois relacionamentos *Many-To-One* nesta classe (`usuario` e `projeto`):

```
        public Atividade()
        {
            Projeto = new Projeto();
            StatusAtividade = EStatusAtividade.NaoIniciado;
            TipoAtividade = ETipoAtividade.NovaImplementacao;
            Usuario = new Usuario();
        }

        [JsonConverter(typeof(FormatoDataNullableConverter))]
        public DateTime? DataHoraFim { get; set; }

        [JsonConverter(typeof(FormatoDataNullableConverter))]
        public DateTime? DataHoraInicio { get; set; }

        public string DescricaoAtividade { get; set; }
        public string EstimativaInicialAtividade { get; set; }
        public Projeto Projeto { get; set; }        

        public string NomeProjeto
        {
            get { return Projeto.Nome; }
        }

        public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

        public string LoginUsuario
        {
            get { return Usuario.Login; }
        }      

        public EStatusAtividade StatusAtividade { get; set; }

        public string DescricaoStatusAtividade
        {
            get { return StatusAtividade.Descricao; }
        }           

        public string DescricaoTipoAtividade
        {
            get { return TipoAtividade.Descricao; }
        }

        public ETipoAtividade TipoAtividade { get; set; }
        public string TituloAtividade { get; set; }


        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return (obj is Atividade) && (obj as Atividade).Codigo.Equals(Codigo);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Codigo.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Na minha classe de repositório, configuro a carga do objeto `Atividade` da seguinte forma:

```
        protected override IQueryable<Atividade> GetEagerLoadConfig()
        {
            return GetModelContext()
                .Include(p => p.Projeto)
                .Include(p => p.Usuario);
        }

        public override Atividade LocalizePorCodigo(long codigo)
        {
            return GetEagerLoadConfig()
                .First(u => u.Codigo.Equals(codigo));
        }
```

Como poderia configurar para que na carga feita no método `GetEagerLoadConfig()`, fosse carregado **apenas** a propriedade código dos objetos Usuario e Projeto, ao invés de carregá-los por completo como está sendo feito? É possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não. Até porque não há necessidade de carregar apenas uma informação, visto que pelo ponto de vista do desempenho o custo de trazer uma coluna ou todos é praticamente idêntico.

Aliás, esta implementação:

```
    protected override IQueryable<Atividade> GetEagerLoadConfig()
    {
        return GetModelContext()
            .Include(p => p.Projeto)
            .Include(p => p.Usuario);
    }

    public override Atividade LocalizePorCodigo(long codigo)
    {
        return GetEagerLoadConfig()
            .First(u => u.Codigo.Equals(codigo));
    }
```

Este código não tem a menor necessidade. [O Entity Framework já implementa um repositório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+entity+framework+reposit%C3%B3rio).

Comment: Entendi Cigano. E em um situação macro (One-To-Many por exemplo) eu posso usar o método .Select() para restringir oq quero, correto? Pois em uma situação One-To-Many o desempenho seria afetado caso carregasse cada objeto por completo.

Comment: esta sobreescrita de `public override Atividade LocalizePorCodigo(long codigo)` realmente não é necessária, mas meu 'repositório' apenas encapsula regras necessárias para minha aplicação, e não apenas implementa o padrão.

Comment: @JoaquimMagalhães Restringir dentro da aplicação, tudo bem. Sem problemas. Mas não, o desempenho é muito pouco afetado se você carregar o objeto no todo ou em partes.

Comment: @JoaquimMagalhães Mas você não ganha **nada** com esse encapsulamento. É mais simples usar a regra diretamente no `DbContext`. Isto é reinvenção da roda.

Comment: Obrigado. Irei notar estes pontos em meus estudos.